# Mysql: n number of columns null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 7 fields and I want to select records having null values in any 3 columns

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Although both answers have flaws, you will know from them how to get the desired result. Apart from that: the task is strange. Is this an exercise from a class? It's hard to imagine a table in a properly designed database where the information that any three fields in a record are null would be helpful.

Comment: What happens if some have 5 null values do you want them or ONLY exactly 3?

Answer (score 2):

Well, as the others are having such a hard time to write the query. Here it goes:

```
select * 
from mytable
where (col1 is null) + (col2 is null) + (col3 is null) + 
      (col4 is null) + (col5 is null) + (col6 is null) + (col7 is null) = 3;
```

This makes use of true = 1 and false = 0 in MySQL. Anyway, what I am doing here is simply counting nulls.

Comment: Awesome. To the point.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from tableName 
having sum((case when column1 is null than 1 end)+
(case when column2 is null than 1 end)+
(case when column3 is null than 1 end)+
(case when column4 is null than 1 end)+
(case when column5 is null than 1 end)+
(case when column6 is null than 1 end)+
(case when column7 is null than 1 end)) >= 3
```

Comment: He is trying to use MYSql Server.

Comment: Why `SUM`? Why `HAVING`? And even mixing `*` with `sum`. Looks very wrong to me.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes * is not need thanks

Comment: Still, the OP has never asked for an aggregation, but for single records.

Comment: How will we get the column values from the resultant(Select)?

Comment: check now ......

Comment: This will give error such: "Column 'tableName.column1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. If used in  SQL.
 
If I execute in MYSQL is not returning any records.

Comment: Really, this isn't so hard to do. Again: Why `SUM`? Why `HAVING`? Why are you trying to aggregate data? Who talked about aggregation?

Comment: what's 1 + null + null + 1 + 1 + null + 1?

Answer (score 0):

**Create Table Script**

```
Create Table SevenColumnTable
(
Col1 varchar(10),
Col2 varchar(10),
Col3 varchar(10),
Col4 varchar(10),
Col5 varchar(10),
Col6 varchar(10),
Col7 varchar(10)
);
```

**Sample Inserts**

```
Insert into SevenColumnTable(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4)
Select 'A','B','C','D';

Insert into SevenColumnTable(Col5,Col2,Col3,Col4)
Select 'A','B','C','D';


Insert into SevenColumnTable(Col2,Col3,Col4)
Select 'A','B','C';


Insert into SevenColumnTable(Col5,Col2,Col3)
Select 'A','B','C';
```

***Select Statement***

```
SELECT * FROM SevenColumnTable where 
ifnull(Col1,1)+ifnull(Col2,1)+ifnull(Col3,1)+ifnull(Col4,1)+ifnull(Col5,1)+ifnull(Col6,1)
+ifnull(Col6,1)=3;
```

Comment: @Wish I did share

Comment: Do you know what `IFNULL` does? It doesn't seem so. The query won't work as expected. See here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: Sorry I might not be an expert at mysql, it giving me result [http://prntscr.com/f99s30]

Comment: `IFNULL(Col1,1)` returns 1 when Col1 is null or Col1 itself otherwise. So `IFNULL(null,1)` returns 1, `IFNULL(1,1)` returns 1, `IFNULL(3,1)` returns 3. Do you really want to make a calculation with the value in Col1-6? I don't think so. Moreover you are using + on a varchar and an int in your sample table. So the column gets converted to number in order to perform an addition. 'A' gets converted to 0, '123' gets converted to 123. (And '12A' gets converted to 12 due to MySQL's very particular way of doing the conversion.) Anyway, you are not only counting null columns here.

Comment: I am just adding the column values to get a count of 3, if the count is not equal to 3 the records must not be included in the result